# How do I get a Gyration Media Center Universal Remote Control (GYR3101CA) working?

Tags: 10.04, mythtv

I have this remote, and I would like to set it up so it's working with Ubuntu and mythtv.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a How To on getting the Gyration Media Center Remote working in Ubuntu 10.04. I have had this remote since 2007, and fell in love with it. The remote is a gyro mouse and media center remote all in one. In order to get this working you have to use a program called Evrouter.

Orginal Information for getting this remote to work was gathered in this thread. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=479897

Write Up:

Open up a terminal window.

Download EVRouter for your architecture:

i386

```
cd ~
wget http://debian.bedroomlan.org/debian/pool/main/e/evrouter/evrouter_0.4_i386.deb
amd64
```

AMD64

```
cd ~
wget http://debian.bedroomlan.org/debian/pool/main/e/evrouter/evrouter_0.4_amd64.deb
```

Install EVRouter:

i386

```
sudo dpkg -i evrouter_0.4_i386.deb
```

amd64

```
sudo dpkg -i evrouter_0.4_amd64.deb
```

Create Configuration file:

Code:

```
cd ~
touch .evrouterrc
nano .evrouterrc
```

Paste the below text.

Code:

```
#   Stop
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/166 "fill this in!"

#   Record
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/167 "XKey/R"

#   Pause
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/167 "XKey/P"

#   Play
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/207 "XKey/P"

#   Rewind
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/168 "XKey/Left"

#   Fast Forward
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/208 "XKey/Right"

#   Skip Back
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/165 "XKey/Home"

#   Skip Forward
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/163 "XKey/End"

#   Guide 
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/362 "XKey/M"

#   Up
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/103 "fill this in!"

#   Left
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/105 "fill this in!"

#   Right
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/106 "fill this in!"

#   Down
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/108 "fill this in!"

#   Back
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/158 "fill this in!"

#   Info
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/130 "XKey/I"

#   OK/Enter
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/28 "fill this in!"

#   Volume Up
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/115 "XKey/F11"

#   Volume Down
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/114 "XKey/F10"

#   Channel Up
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/402 "XKey/Up"

#   Channel Down
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/403 "XKey/Down"

#   Mute
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/113 "XKey/F9"

#   1
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/2 "fill this in!"
# 
#   2
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/3 "fill this in!"
# 
#   3
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/4 "fill this in!"
# 
#   4
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/5 "fill this in!"
# 
#   5
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/6 "fill this in!"
# 
#   6
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/7 "fill this in!"
# 
#   7
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/8 "fill this in!"
# 
#   8
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/9 "fill this in!"
# 
#   9
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/10 "fill this in!"
# 
#   0
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/11 "fill this in!"
# 
#   *
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/42 "fill this in!"
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/9 "fill this in!"
# 
#   #
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/42 "fill this in!"
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/4 "fill this in!"

#   Clear
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd" none key/1 "fill this in!"
# 
#   Left Click
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/272 "fill this in!"
# 
#   Right Click
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/273 "fill this in!"

#   Live TV
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/377 "XKey/C"

#   Windows
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/102 "XKey/Alt_L+Control_L+BackSpace"

#   Pictures
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/226 "fill this in!"
# 
#   Music
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/391 "fill this in!"
# 
#   Video
# "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/393 "fill this in!"

#   DVD Menu
"Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/410 "XKey/O"
```

Create start file.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo touch evrouter_start.sh
sudo nano evrouter_start.sh
sudo chmod 4777 evrouter_start.sh
```

Paste the below into the file.

```
xhost +local:root
killall evrouter
rm /tmp/.evrouter* #removes a previous lock file
/usr/bin/evrouter /dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse /dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyr
ation_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd &
```

Create autostart file.

```
cd ~
cd .config/autostart
touch evrouter.desktop
nano evrouter.desktop
chmod 4777 evrouter.desktop
```

Paste the below text.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Evrouter
Comment=
GenericName=Evrouter Process
Exec=/usr/local/bin/evrouter_start.sh
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=
Categories=GNOME;Application;AudioVideo;Audio;Video
X-AppInstall-Package=Evrouter
```

Get event ID: 
Run

```
ls -l /dev/input/by-id/
```

Above command should return information like below.

```
demonbob@sys-mythtv:/etc/udev/rules.d$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-08-25 23:44 usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-08-25 23:44 usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-08-25 23:44 usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-mouse -> ../mouse1
Write down the event# associate with usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-kbd and usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse. In my case this is 3 and 4.
```

Create udev rules file.

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d
sudo touch 10-local.rules
sudo nano 10-local.rules
```

Paste the below into terminal. Replace the event[#,#] with your corresponding numbers. Change the owner to the your user account

```
KERNEL=="event[3,4]", OWNER="YOUR_USERNAME"
```

Reboot

### Extras

Jump Points:

Custom Scripts:

MythFrontend Close and Stop when green MCE button is pressed.

I wrote a script to make the Green MCE button to start and stop mythfrontend

1. Download the attachement labeled mce.start.sh
2. copy the file to /usr/local/bin/
3. Change the premissions of the file to executable.

   ```
   sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/bin/mce.start.sh
   ```
4. Edit your .evrouterrc for key event 102 and make it look like so. (Notice the change at the end)

   "Gyration Gyration RF Technology Receiver" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gyration_Gyration_RF_Technology_Receiver-event-mouse" none key/102 "Shell/mce.start.sh &"

Mythfrontend swith to boxee

This is a simple replacement for the above script for if you have multiple media clients installed you can switch between them. In the code below i use boxee, but it can be modified for any combinations of applications.

Code:

```
if [ "$(pidof mythfrontend.real)" ] && [ "$(pidof Boxee)" ]
then
    killall mythfrontend.real
    killall Boxee


elif [ "$(pidof mythfrontend.real)" ]
then
    killall mythfrontend.real
    exec /opt/boxee/run-boxee-desktop

elif [ "$(pidof Boxee)" ]
then

    killall Boxee
else

    exec mythfrontend

fi
```

#### References

- [Original forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4579356#post4579356).